# Display loading.gif while uploading a file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to show `loading.gif` while uploading a file using jQuery?

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="profilepic" id="profilepic" accept="image/*" required >
<div id="loader_img"></div>

<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Save</button>
```

When I click on the `save` button, `loading.gif` has to be shown while loading a file.

This is my jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('form[name="chngimg"]').find('input,select,textarea').not('[type=submit]').jqBootstrapValidation({
    submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {

      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "propicchng.php",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
             $('#loader_img').show();

                          // just to confirm ajax submission
          $("#imgchng").modal('hide');
                    alert(msg);
                    $( '#chngimg-form' ).each(function(){
                     this.reset();
                     });},
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
                }
                });
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why `$('#loader_img').show();` is located in `success` callback ?

Comment: i am not good in jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What **@Mehran Torki** is saying is that you need to first put the loader to show before the request - and then hide it in success callback. This is how your code should look like to show the loader - mind the comments!

```
$(function() {
  $('form[name="chngimg"]').find('input,select,textarea').not('[type=submit]').jqBootstrapValidation({
    submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
      //here - showing loader to the user
      $('#loader_img').show();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "propicchng.php",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(msg){
          //here - hiding when request is done
          $('#loader_img').hide();
          // just to confirm ajax submission
          $("#imgchng").modal('hide');
          alert(msg);
          $( '#chngimg-form' ).each(function(){
            this.reset();
          });},
        error: function(){
          alert("failure");
        }
      });
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```